# Converting chars to integers is creating a negative number?

Tags: c, function, loops, char, integer

I am trying to find the mean of an array of chars. I assume I need to convert the chars to integer before I perform a mathematical operation on them so I do that and then convert it back to char at the end.

The problem I am seeing is that any char with 3 digits is converting to a negative integer value. The two digit values print out perfectly. I am able to see this by doing a print statement within the for loop. See output below:

[image]

My code is below:

```
void main() {
  int max;
  int min;
  int median;
  int mean;

  unsigned char test[SIZE] = { 34, 201, 190, 154,   8, 194,   2,   6,
                              114, 88,   45,  76, 123,  87,  25,  23,
                              200, 122, 150, 90,   92,  87, 177, 244,
                              201,   6,  12,  60,   8,   2,   5,  67,
                                7,  87, 250, 230,  99,   3, 100,  90};


  mean = find_mean(test);
  printf("%d", mean);
  /* Statistics and Printing Functions Go Here */

}

char find_mean(char * x) {
  
 int value = 0;
 int sum = 0; 
 int mean = 0;
 char mean_char;   

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    int value = x[i];
    printf("%d\n", value);
    sum += value;
  }

  printf("%d", sum);
  mean = sum/SIZE;
  mean_char = mean;
  return mean_char;  

}
```

Comment: You used `unsigned char` in one place but not all of them. Why?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. You can copy and past the text from your console window directly into your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
char find_mean(char * x)
```

to this:

```
unsigned char find_mean(unsigned char * x)
```

since your array is of type `unsigned char`. Same change for:

```
char mean_char;
```

to:

```
unsigned char mean_char;
```

Now your output is  (after changing sum print to `printf("%d\n", sum);`):

```
...
3759
mean = 93
```

which is correct, since `SIZE` is 40, and so 3759/40 = 93.

---

Enable **Compiler Warnings** to easily catch such issues. For example in GCC with `-Wall -Wextra` flags passed, I get:

```
prog.c:22:20: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'find_mean' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
   22 |   mean = find_mean(test);
      |                    ^~~~
      |                    |
      |                    unsigned char *
prog.c:7:23: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'unsigned char *'
    7 | char find_mean(char * x);
      |                ~~~~~~~^
```

Comment: thank you, i should have paid more attention to the char types!